# How to make my android game fit to all screen resolution?

Tags: android, layout, resolution

I wanted to create a small game on android and then I realize that there is a problem with a screen resolution. I don't know how to make my game's control (Buttons, Textview, etc) will look good to all the screen resolution like (tablet and normal android device) that have different pixel. Like if I design layout for android phone and then if I run it on tablet then buttons, or any controls will look small. So the question is that how to make it (all controls) look more fit and good for any different pixel or resolution device?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Answer (score 0):

You have to create seperate layouts for phablets tablets etc. create 5 folders under res directory.
layout-ldpi
layout-hdpi
layout-mdpi
layout-xdpi
layout-xxdpi
Then copy your file which by default in your layout folder and paste it in a all above folders. Then you have toh manually set the contents for different views . It is a very very boring tedious task